# What is "degenerate" about degenerate quadratic surfaces?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, euclidean-geometry

In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_surface) the table of quadratic surfaces is divided into 2 parts, the second being "degenerate quadrics". Why is this distinction made? and what does the word degenerate means in this case?

Comment: Degenerate quadrics contain singular points. Maybe it is more clear if you read this: http://math.ucdenver.edu/~tvis/Teaching/4220spring09/Assignments/Brook_Le.pdf

Comment: Dear @Beni, some of the degenerate quadrics in the wikipedia article (for example the elliptic cylinder) are as non-singular as one may wish, so that's not the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia's point of view is that one should homogeneize the  equation, write it as $Q(x,y,z,t)=0$ and check whether that *homogeneous* form $Q$ is degenerate or not.
And to see if a quadratic form is degenerate, you have to construct the bilinear form from which it comes;  degeneracy means that the matrix (in any basis) of that bilinear form has zero determinant.
In the case at hand it is very easy to see that the  forms labeled as "degenerate" are indeed degenerate, because the corresponding quadratic form contains at most three of the four variables $x,y,z$ and $t$,  so  that the matrix referred to above has a line of zeros!